# Bulk Edit Selected Cells in DataGrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to bulk edit selected cells in a column so that when you type to edit, all cells are affected. However, what I've found is when you select the cells (with SelectionUnit property of DataGrid set to "Cell"), and start typing, it starts editing only the last cell...

Is there a way we can manipulate the event handling of DataGrid so that this is achievable? i.e. editing takes place in all cells at real-time?

Comment: Anyone know..??